# Import-CSV and Foreach

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

I've got a huge comma seperated CSV-list with IP-addresses of my network that I want to run queries against. Example of my CSV input:

```
172.168.0.1,172.168.0.2,172.168.0.3,172.168.0.4
```

Etc....

When I run the following code to test for the output:

```
$filepath = "c:\scripts\servers.csv" 
$servers = Import-CSV $filepath -delimiter "," 

Foreach ($server in $servers) {
     write-host $server

}
```

I get no output, I think it's because there are no headers specified. I can obviously do a workaround and open the CSV-file and type in all the headers. Are there any other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create the headers on the fly (no need to specify delimiter when the delimiter is a comma):

```
Import-CSV $filepath -Header IP1,IP2,IP3,IP4 | Foreach-Object{
   Write-Host $_.IP1
   Write-Host $_.IP2
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. Sadly the CSV contains about 100 IP-adresses all on the same line, so do I have to specify 100 headers?

Comment: I created 1 header called "IP" and placed all the IP-adresses under it. Workaround, but it works now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$IP_Array = (Get-Content test2.csv)[0].split(",")
foreach ( $IP in $IP_Array){
    $IP
}
```

Get-content Filename returns an array of strings for each line.

On the first string only, I split it based on ",".  Dumping it into $IP_Array.

```
$IP_Array = (Get-Content test2.csv)[0].split(",")
foreach ( $IP in $IP_Array){
  if ($IP -eq "2.2.2.2") {
    Write-Host "Found $IP"
  }
}
```

Comment: While this would work for simple CSV files, it will fail where commas are part of the field values.

Comment: Why would there be a comma as part of the field name in a comma delimited file?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to change Delimiter.

Content of the csv file  -> Note .. Also space and , in value

Values are 6 Dutch word aap,noot,mies,Piet, Gijs, Jan

```
Col1;Col2;Col3

a,ap;noo,t;mi es

P,iet;G ,ijs;Ja ,n



$csv = Import-Csv C:\TejaCopy.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Answer:

```
Write-Host $csv
@{Col1=a,ap; Col2=noo,t; Col3=mi es} @{Col1=P,iet; Col2=G ,ijs; Col3=Ja ,n}
```

It is possible to read a CSV file and use other Delimiter to separate each column.

It worked for my script :-)

Answer (score 0):

$filepath = ".\ADcomputerslist.csv"
$servers = Import-CSV $filepath -delimiter ","

Foreach ($entry in $servers) { write-host $entry.name }

## also can replace stupid file with object.

$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,ipv4Address

Foreach ($entry in $servers) { write-host $entry.name }

Comment: please add code format markers to your Answer. as of now, it is annoying to try t read your code. [*grin*]